Base64 Conversion Error in DART of GitHub API
I am using the GitHub API to fetch the README of my repository. The content of the README comes encoded in base64. When I try to decode it in Flutter/Dart, I encounter a FormatException: Invalid character error. Here is the error message:
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Invalid character (at character 61)
PGRpdiBhbGlnbj0iY2VudGVyIj4KCiMgTmFtYXN0ZSDwn5mPLCBJJ20gRGVl
                                                            ^

#0      _Base64Decoder.decodeChunk (dart:convert/base64.dart:705:7)
#1      _Base64Decoder.decode (dart:convert/base64.dart:629:14)
#2      Base64Decoder.convert (dart:convert/base64.dart:509:26)
#3      Base64Codec.decode (dart:convert/base64.dart:83:47)
#4      main (file:///home/deepesh/Development/public/learn/flutter-dart/git_search_flutter/learn.dart:6:24)
#5      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#6      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

Then I read some stack overflow comment that it is strick encoding, i was finding the how strick encoding work on dart it was nothing, i can found it.
import 'dart:convert';

const content =
    "PGRpdiBhbGlnbj0iY2VudGVyIj4KCiMgTmFtYXN0ZSDwn5mPLCBJJ20gRGVl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\nCgoKCjwvZGl2Pg==\n";

void main() {
  var decoder = base64.decode(content);
  print(decoder);

}

here content is my readme file in base64 encoding claim by github api response
https://api.github.com/repos/DeepeshKalura/DeepeshKalura/readme endpoint, i guess it is public so, no issue you will get same result
Currently, i am manaing with the exception handling
import 'dart:convert';
late String markdown;

  Future<String> markdownFunction() async {
    var profileMarkdown = await profileRenderKernaHai();
    var bodyMarkdown = profileMarkdown?.content;

    if (bodyMarkdown == null) {
      return "No Markdown";
    } else {
      // Log the base64 string for debugging
      print('Base64 String: $bodyMarkdown');

      // Sanitize the input by removing any extraneous whitespace
      bodyMarkdown = bodyMarkdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\s+'), '');

      // Ensure proper padding
      while (bodyMarkdown!.length % 4 != 0) {
        bodyMarkdown += '=';
      }

      try {
        var decoded = base64.decode(bodyMarkdown);
        return utf8.decode(decoded);
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle the error or log it
        print('Error decoding base64 string: $e');
        return "Error: Invalid Markdown";
      }
    }
  }


Excepted result an readme file, just like here.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DeepeshKalura/DeepeshKalura/main/README.md

void main() async { final readme = await Stream.value(content) .transform(LineSplitter()) .transform(base64.decoder) .transform(utf8.decoder) .toList(); print(readme.join()); }

btw, i used Stream API because you can use a Stream directly from your api response - i mean you dont have to convert the whole response to a String - so instead Stream.value(content) just use your api response Stream

I got a json from github API, convert in a class by somekind of extension and access that. profileRenderKernaHai() this function do all this thing and return me the class as future response so, I don't understand this Stream<List>? part of your. @pskink

so did you try the code from my first comment?  and if you dont want to go the "stream" way simply remove all "\n" from your content and pass it to base64.decode() method

yes! I  tried, and it works great! I don't know the concept of stream API yet.  My assumption was error came due to the "\n" new line encoding and maybe there is no stick base-64 encoding that does not recognise \n is a new line. So, we have to transform with LineSplitter(). But I does not implemented it in my app yet. Stream<List> ? still i don't know what you are trying to say. Sorry but currently I working on running Macos in VM in Linux so, I can create my app both for ios and Android. So, not be able to try the StreamAPI concept. @pskink Thanks for your help

ok if you want to make it easy way (and because your content comes from json and not from "stream") just do base64.decode(content.replaceAll('\n', '')); - thats all

@pskink thanks brother great help, you can sumbit as the answer i will accept that

your welcome, feel free to submit a self answer then :-)
